# Camera intent.getData() return null in some devices,Mainly in android 7.0

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-camera, android-bitmap

Camera  intent.getData() return null,In some devices.

Start camera for result,

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

I tried following code get path of Uri of image,

```
public static Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

It will give me Uri of image but **image quality will become poor**.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Camera intent.getData() return null,In some devices.

It is supposed to return `null` for all camera apps.

> I tried following code get path of Uri of image

That code does not "get path of Uri of image". It saves the `Bitmap` to a random, undocumented file, then returns a `Uri` from the `MediaStore` representing that content.

It also wastes heap space, as you create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, write a JPEG into it, and then throw that all away.

> image quality will become poor

The image quality was poor to begin with, as you asked the camera app to give you a thumbnail image. Use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to tell the camera app where to save a full-resolution image, then use that location in `onActivityResult()`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content) demonstrates this.

Comment: give permission to write external memory, also check permission at runtime